# spaMM::fitme() - error troubleshooting and application to longitudinal data

Tags: r, mixed-model

I'm trying to fit a GLMM that accounts for spatial autocorrelation (SAC) using the spaMM::fitme() function in R.
I have a longitudinal data set where observations were collected repeatedly from a number of sites over 13 years. I'm interested in understanding what the effect of time (year) is on the dependent variable (y), as well as the fixed effect of a categorical variable (class) while accounting for the random factors biome, continent, and ID (a unique ID for each site sampled). My data set contains ~ 180 000 rows.

I have two questions:

1. When trying to run the following model (M1) with the full data set, I get this error:

```
    M1 <- fitme(y ~ year + class + (1|biome) + (1|continent) + (1|ID) + Matern(1|long + lat), data = df, family = "gaussian", method = "REML")
    
    Error in ZA %*% xmatrix : 
      Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

After a bit of googling, it seems like this could be a matter of not enough RAM. I've tried running this model on a device with 64GB and got the same error. How can I be sure that this is in fact the problem that's causing this error?

2. I'm uncertain if this is an appropriate way of applying the spaMM::fitme() function to longitudinal data. I have some experience with fitting GLS models that account for SAC to a longitudinal data set where I had to group my data set by year using the nlme::groupedData() function before fitting the model. Does a similar method need to be used in the case of spaMM:fitme() and longitudinal data?

Sarah

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it might be better on datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can set a breakpoint in the code and inspect the size of the objects. It looks like the line in the code is in the function `.more_init_optim` in this [source file](https://rdrr.io/cran/spaMM/src/R/HLfit_Internals.R). If you stuggle to set a breakpoint then look at the call stack and trace the code back from that line to figure out the size of the objects. This type of model is complex so that may prove to be quite arduous. If I were you I would just use a bigger machine (more RAM) and if that solves the problem then you will have the answer. The error message does look like an insufficient RAM problem though.
2. From a quick look at the documentation it seems you are on the right track.

You might get better answers at a specific resource for mixed models in R,  such as the [R-Sig-Me mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models). I see that the author of the `spaMM` package is a contributor there.

Unfortunately, the question is a bit too software specific for here

Comment: Thanks @Robert Long for the tips. I've submitted my second question to the R-Sig-Me mailing list, so will hopefully find some answers there. Regarding my first question, can you explain in a bit more detail how to set a breakpoint in the fitme() code and check the size of objects? I've tried following some guides online, but I'm uncertain about where in the code I should set a breakpoint. I don't have any experience with debugging R code..

Comment: These are the guides I've tried following: [Debugging with RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#debugging-in-packages) and [How to set breakpoints for package functions in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015787/how-to-set-breakpoints-for-package-functions-in-rstudio).

Comment: I've edited my answer. Unfortunately this is really not on topic here. You could ask on stackoverflow about debugging, which is a good skill to have, though hopefully you will get an answer on R-sig-me